# Cómo saber si una consulta oracle tiene resultado vacío

Tags: php, oracle

Tengo una duda sobra la forma de comprobar si un array está vacío en una conexión Oracle. En MySql si consigo hacerlo con el mysql_num_rows, pero en Oracle, el oci_num_rows creo que no funciona igual, y me estoy volviendo loco.

El ejemplo es este:

```
$query_pe="SELECT campo1
           FROM tabla 
           WHERE campo2='$valor'";
$datos_pe = oci_parse($oracle_con, $query_pe);
oci_execute($datos_pe);
if(oci_num_rows($datos_pe)>0){
    while($fila_pe = oci_fetch_array($datos_pe, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)){
    echo "Valor OK<br>";
    }
}else{
    echo "No se encuentra el valor<br>";
}
```

El problema es que la función "oci_num_rows" me devuelve 0 siempre.
¿Alguien me puede decir alguna forma de hacer esta comprobación?

Mil gracias de antemano.

Comment: Has comprobado que la query que quieres lanzar es la correcta?

Comment: Hola Mario, si que lo comprobé con varias y no había manera. En la respuesta de Arreguin92 me ha aclarado el funcionamiento de este tipo de consultas en Oracle. Muchas gracias por tu atención!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como lo dice la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.oci-num-rows.php) de PHP para la función `oci_num_rows()`:

> Nota: Esta función no devuelve el número de filas seleccionadas. Para sentencias SELECT, esta función devolverá el número de filas que fueron obtenidas desde el búfer con funciones de tipo oci_fetch*().

Lo que puedes hacer es usar la función `oci_fetch_all()` que en su [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.oci-fetch-all.php) menciona:

> Devuelve el número de filas de output, el cual podría ser cero o más, o FALSE en caso de error.

Por lo que tu código podría quedar así:

```
$query_pe="SELECT campo1
           FROM tabla 
           WHERE campo2='$valor'";
$datos_pe = oci_parse($oracle_con, $query_pe);
oci_execute($datos_pe);
$numero_filas = oci_fetch_all($datos_pe, $filas_resultado);
if($numero_filas > 0){
    foreach ($filas_resultado as $fila){
        echo "Valor OK<br>";
    }
}else{
    echo "No se encuentra el valor<br>";
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Arreguin92!!! Me has aclarado el funcionamiento de este tipo de consultas que no lo tenía muy claro. Te agradezco mucho tu atención. Un saludo!